# javac with MigLayout

Tags: jar, javac, executable-jar, miglayout

I've spent the past week trying to figure this issue out...hopefully someone can help.

I created a Java project that uses MigLayout. I've added the jar file to the same directory where my main class is.

i.e.

- java/

  - Main.java ...contains main() method
  - MigLayout/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar

**It doesn't matter which editor I use, I can compile/run the file and it executes flawlessly.**

The issue starts when I try to create a jar file, or compile with cmd. If, for example, in IntelliJ I build the artifact (build the Jar file), it builds it...but it won't run it when I double click on it.

If I use javac in cmd, it gives me this error:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Main.java:8: error: package net.miginfocom.swing does not exist
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
                       ^
Main.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
        menuPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
                               ^
  symbol:   class MigLayout
  location: class Main
2 errors
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Any help would be great.

**SOLVED**

OK, so I got it working. This is what I did:

- I created a new folder and moved all of the src files into the src folder there
- I made sure to remove all other files that weren't java related, such as the Manifest file
- I previously downloaded the MigLayout and json jars and placed them into the src folder as well (*that's how I originally got the code to compile*)
- I opened up IntelliJ and clicked **File** -> **New** -> **Project from existing source**
- I selected the folder that contained the src folder
- I ran through the prompts. I noticed that it was finding everything: MigLayout and JSON jars
- After it was complete, I made sure that it would compile in IntelliJ and it did.
- Next, as I did before, I clicked **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Artifacts**
- I clicked the **Plus** button and selected **JAR From Modules with dependencies.** I selected the file containing the main method
- I checked the **Build on make** option that's right below the Output directory
- I clicked Apply and OK.
- Next I clicked **Build** and **Build Artifacts**
- I selected **Jar** and **Build Jar**
- Went to the out folder and it was there
- I double clicked on it and everything worked!